# Android testing - AmbigiousViewMatcherException

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, testing

I am currently in the process of writing Android Espresso tests for my application.

The issue is, I have an item with the same name in two layouts (both are being used by my main activity, so when i launch main activity using @get:Rule annotation I get both layouts). I am trying to write a test for it, but, as expected, it shows AmbigiousViewMatcherExpression.

How can i specify to which item i am referring to, without changing the name of the item in one of the layouts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `inRoot` method provided by Espresso to specify the root view from which to search for a view.

```
onView(withText("My Text"))
    .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(activityTestRule.activity.window.decorView))))
    .perform(click());
```

In here, the `withDecorView` method is used to specify the root view of the second layout, and `not(is(activityTestRule.activity.window.decorView))` is used to exclude the first layout as the root view.   This way, Espresso will search for the view only in the second layout.
You can adapt this approach to your specific case by using the appropriate view matcher to identify the views you want to interact with, and by specifying the root view using the `inRoot` method.

Comment: Thank You for Your help. However, I have another dilemma. I tried doing this, but it says that activity is "unnamed reference". Am i doing something wrong? I added all the offered imports and instead of activityTestRule put the activity from this rule:  @get:Rule
    var tasksfragmentRule: ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

Comment: I also tried using the name of activity controlling this fragment, TasksFragmentActivities instead, but the same issue persist. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mabey you might be using the wrong reference for the activity in your test code?   Instead of using `activity`,  you should try use the reference to the activity that you created with the `ActivityScenarioRule`.

Comment: For anyone out there wondering, the solution was in giving an id to the parent layout closest to the problematic element, and then using withParent in a test. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in giving an id to the parent layout closest to the problematic element, and then using withParent in a test.